# Tallinn APC & AVL data for public transport

Tags: government, transportation, city, public-transport

I am looking for automatic passenger counts (APC) and automatic vehicle location (AVL) datasets for Tallinn public transportation system. Any ideas where I can find them?

Or if there are no such data publicly available are there any other cities that make such datasets publicly available? Are there any other interesting datasets to research public transportation as a whole?

Any ideas?

Comment: take a scroll through other similar questions https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=public+transport